# Create JSON array from seperate []byte results in GoLang

Tags: arrays, json, go, tiedot

I have a loop of results coming from a [tiedot](https://github.com/HouzuoGuo/tiedot) query.

In it's most basic form it looks like this:

```
col.ForEachDoc(func(id int, docContent []byte) (willMoveOn bool) {
    return true
    return false
})
```

I can send these results down the pipe to the client, but only 1 at a time. Not quite what I want.

I can also create single JSON objects, using json.Unmarshal but how do I combine them all into 1 large JSON array?

Many thanks. New to GO!

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you mean with JSON array. Do you mean an array you can index, where each element is a dictionary, or do you mean a text json representation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are returning this directly to the client and your `docContent` is JSON you can just manually construct the array syntax. It does not provide any safety if `docContent` is not valid json.

```
a := [][]byte{}

col.ForEachDoc(func(id int, docContent []byte) (willMoveOn bool) {
     a = append(a, docContent)
     return true
})
b := bytes.Join(a, []byte(`,`))

// insert '[' to the front
b = append(b, 0)
copy(b[1:], b[0:])
b[0] = byte('[')

// append ']'
b = append(b, ']')
```

You could also unmarshal, then append to a slice, then marshal the slice

```
s := []interface{}{}
col.ForEachDoc(func(id int, docContent []byte) (willMoveOn bool) {
     var j interface{}
     if err := json.Unmarshal(docContent, &j); err != nil {
          // handle error
     }
     s = append(s, j)
     return true
})

b, err := json.Marshal(j)
```